# Sum of all possible combinations in a set

Tags: summation, combinations

Consider the set of natural numbers $\lbrace 1,2,3,\cdots,n \rbrace$. Take all possible combinations of $m$ numbers chosen from this set ($m \leq n$, no repetitions), add the numbers in each combination and then add the resulting numbers together. Is there a formula for the final result of such an operation in terms of $n$ and $m$?

For example, if $m=1$, the result is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. For $m=2$, the sum
\begin{align}
&\big(1+2)+(1+3)+ (1+4)+\cdots+(1+n) 
\\
+ &(2+3) +(2+4)+\cdots+(2+n) 
\\
+&(3+4) + \cdots + (3+n)
\\
&\vdots
\\
+ &((n-1)+n) 
\end{align}

needs to be evaluated. Although I'm guessing this might be calculated directly, I am not sure if such a direct calculation would be feasible for larger $m$'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of this differently. How many times will the number $i$ will count in the sum ? well, it will be part of exactly ${n-1\choose m-1}$ of the combinations you consider. Therefore if $S$ is the sum you are looking for, you get
\begin{align*}
S &= {n-1\choose m-1}\sum_{i=1}^n i\\
&= {n-1\choose m-1} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{align*}

---

For illustration, in your example, the number of $1$ in your sum is the same as the number of $2$ indeed you remove one in the line but one comes from above. Then it is also the same as for $3$, etc... It is also the same as the number of $n$ since you take one a each line.